# Generate a script to drop a DB user

Tags: t-sql

I have a script below to search ALL DBs for a specific user:

```
DECLARE @DBuser_sql VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DBuser_table TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(200), UserName VARCHAR(250))

SET @DBuser_sql='SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,a.name AS Name FROM ?.sys.database_principals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id=b.member_principal_id
WHERE a.sid NOT IN (0x01,0x00) AND a.sid IS NOT NULL AND a.type NOT IN (''C'') AND a.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND a.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY Name'
INSERT @DBuser_table
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@dbuser_sql
SELECT * FROM @DBuser_table
where username = 'frodo'
ORDER BY DBName
```

The top part of the image below is the result of the script. the bottom part is what i want to create based on the result.

[image]

Comment: You want to drop the user `frodo` from all roles in all databases? Are they an SQL user or a Windows user?

Comment: To add onto to Charlieface's question, would it be sufficient to just `DROP` the user from the database itself (instead of iterating through every role in that database)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DBuser_sql VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DBuser_table TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(200), UserName VARCHAR(250))

SET @DBuser_sql = 
'SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,a.name AS Name FROM ?.sys.database_principals a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id=b.member_principal_id
WHERE a.sid NOT IN (0x01,0x00) AND a.sid IS NOT NULL AND a.type NOT IN (''C'') AND a.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND a.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY Name'
INSERT @DBuser_table

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@dbuser_sql

SELECT 'USE [' + DBName + ']; ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [' + UserName +'];' FROM @DBuser_table
where username = 'frodo'
ORDER BY DBName
```